# How to bring a Progress Bar in front of a Button in older API versions?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-button, android-progressbar

I read two articles about this topic, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934236/how-to-make-a-progress-bar-show-on-top-of-a-button-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216080/how-to-bring-imageview-in-front-of-button-in-android-5).

But both tell solutions like changing the elevation or translations.

The question is about bringing a Progress bar in front of a button in older versions that don't support elevation or translation attributes.

How can I do this in XML and in Java?!

Or it is not valid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.business.abdelhafiz.omar.civiltaif.LoginActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/home_civil"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progressbar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_email"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/login_email"
        android:onClick="loginEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_anonymous"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_email"
        android:text="@string/login_anonymous"
        android:onClick="loginAnonymous"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is a screen shot

[image]

I want to bring the progress bar in front of the buttons

Edit:

Nothing worked for me so I will just hide the buttons when I need to show the progress bar.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343213/progressbar-on-top-of-button-in-relative-layout-issue-in-android-studio/31343665

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can move it to the bottom like this

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/home_civil"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_email"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/login_email"
    android:onClick="loginEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_anonymous"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/login_email"
    android:text="@string/login_anonymous"
    android:onClick="loginAnonymous"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progressbar"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_height"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height" />
```

or in `onCreate` method just write `login_progressbar.bringToFront();`

Comment: I moved it to the bottom of the layout

Comment: and added the bringToFront method but still doesn't work

Comment: clean and rebuild your project

Comment: i will try to clean and rebuild

Answer (score 4):

[image]Here the solution, i just change the order of my elements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.business.abdelhafiz.omar.civiltaif.LoginActivity">
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/home_civil"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_email"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/login_email"
    android:onClick="loginEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_anonymous"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/login_email"
    android:text="@string/login_anonymous"
    android:onClick="loginAnonymous"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progressbar"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_height"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height" 
    android:background=""/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

i added background to progress to see that the progress is in front the buttons

Comment: the question was how to bring a progress bar in front of a button

Comment: Ok, so can you join a screenshot of what you need ?

Comment: here is a screen shot

Comment: Ok i update the answer tell me if that works for you

Comment: changing the order doesn't help

Comment: Using a RelativeLayout the order of elements change their disposition, i ve test this code and it works for me. i show you the screenshot

Comment: i will try what you said

Comment: i made a new layout and added just a button and a progress bar and still the button overlaps the button

Comment: what android studio version do you use

Comment: what is your target, compile and min sdk

Comment: also i did copy your exact same code above and still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Set an elevation on the ProgressBar; 2dp seems to work.

```
android:elevation="2dp"
```

You could also try setting translationZ as suggested in the accepted answer to a similar question.

I also came across this answer as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

For me the elevation on the ProgressBar needed to be 4dp, because the Button had already a 2dp elevation by design.

```
android:elevation="4dp"
```